# dax studio - Filtering Data

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, measure

Using DAX studio, I'm trying to understand what data this filter function is pulling.

```
EVALUATE
   FILTER ( 'TM Freight Charges', 
       'TM Freight Charges'[Related Order Type] = Fact_Table[Order Type])
```

However, I get the following error message:
[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBUMo.png)

ultimately, I'm trying to evaluate this particular filter formula

```
Evaluate
  FILTER ('TM Freight Charges',
                    AND (
                        AND (
                            AND (
                                'TM Freight Charges'[Related Order Type] = [Order Type],
                                'TM Freight Charges'[Related Order Number] = [Order Number]
                            ),
                            'TM Freight Charges'[Volume] = Fact_Table[Volume]
                        ),
                        'TM Freight Charges'[Charge Type] = "BASE"
                    )
                )
            )
```

If this was a SQL problem, I would just do an INNER JOIN along with some WHERE statements, but in DAX Studio, I don't have a clue. Help?

Comment: In your data model, do you have relationships between these tables (Freight Charges and Fact table)?

Comment: yes there is relationship between freight charge table another intermediary table, which in turn has a relationship with the fact table.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify an 'equal' on the filter, you should pass a value or a list or something. If you are doing that on a row context (for example adding a column to a table), the way you did it will work, but on building a table there's no context for that. Did you try something like:

```
EVALUATE
   FILTER ( 'TM Freight Charges', 
       'TM Freight Charges'[Related Order Type] IN Fact_Table[Order Type])
```

or:

```
EVALUATE
   FILTER ( 'TM Freight Charges', 
       'TM Freight Charges'[Related Order Type] IN VALUES ( Fact_Table[Order Type]) )
```

Cheers!